# Redirection of Complex Index.php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

> Hi i have a website and i have used some htaccess redirect code to make SEO and User friendly URLs
>
> This is the htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.niresh12495.com/ [R=301,L] 

The Second Code is used to redirect /index.php to root 

at the same time urls like http://www.niresh12495.com/index.php?app=upload are not 
user friendly
```

but www.niresh12495.com/index.php? is not  redirected to home page www.nresh12495.com/

i have tried some other htaccess code to remove index.php they result in urls like

www.niresh12495.com/?app=core&module=global&section=login

instead of

www.niresh12495.com/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login

if the url is changed like above no body can login or even create a new topic this is the problem

how can i redirect http://www.niresh12495.com/index.php? to root without messing with forum login and posting issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [NC,R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index\.php [L]
```

`?` in the end will strip any existing query string.

Comment: i have tried this code the problem is it redirect index.php to but not index.php? can you solve this?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the comment, pls clarify?

Comment: hi i have added this in my htaccess http://www.niresh12495.com/index.php is redirected to root but http://www.niresh12495.com/index.php? with a question mark is not redirected to root thats my problem? please type that url in your browser @anubhava